# within the context of Cypress: How to wait for a Apollo Client Graphql request

Tags: graphql, apollo, cypress

In my tests I execute graphql queries via a ApolloClient and mutations to set up my data.  Using cypress how do I set this up so I can wait for those steps to executed before proceeding:

right now I am hacking it like so ...

```js
  cy.wrap(null)
    .then(() => register({ email, template: 'basic' }))
    .then(() => {
      login(email);
    })
    .then(resp => console.log('Logged IN: ', resp));

  console.log('Hello [This logs out BEFORE the logged in -- i want to wait]') 
  cy.wait(1000);
  cy.visit('/');
```

but I would like to wait for the entire cy.wrap block.

Anyone have a good working solution.

Thanks!

---

in case it is useful, the two referenced methods look like the following.
TestClient is an instance of ApolloClient

```js
export function login(email: string) {
  const client = new TestClient();

  return client
    .mutate<LoginMutation, LoginMutationVariables>({
      mutation: loginMutation,
      variables: { email }
    })
    .then(resp => {
      cy.setCookie('token', resp!.data!.login!.token!);
      return resp;
    });
}
```

and

```js
export function register(input: IRegisterInput) {
  const { email } = input;
  const name = input.name || faker.name.findName();
  return createInvitation(email, name).then(invitaitonResponse => {
    const inviteCode = invitaitonResponse.data!.createInvitation!.invitation!.inviteCode!;

    let variables: RegisterMutationVariables = { email, inviteCode };

    if (input.template) {
      variables.template = input.template;
    }

    const client = new TestClient();
    return client.mutate<RegisterMutation, RegisterMutationVariables>({
      mutation: registerMutation,
      variables: { email, inviteCode }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: This isn&amp;#39;t enough information to answer your question. What are those functions you&amp;#39;re calling returning? register and login

Comment: @bkucera -- added to the body of the query.  Thx

Comment: cypress will await all the promises that are being returned from those functions, so can you explain more about the "steps" not being awaited?

Comment: (I added a console log to the code) -- the console.log("Hello") fires BEFORE the console.log("Logged in") -- so it is not being awaited

Comment: No, Cypress commands are enqueued synchronously, but cypress waits to execute them on its own. Console.log is not a Cypress command

Comment: Try cy.visit().then

Comment: @bkucera -- I am not sure where you want me to use cy.visit  instead of using ApolloClient to execute the query.  That is less than ideal.

Comment: sorry, I mean put the console.log in a .then after your visit, like this `cy.visit().then(()=>{console.log(...)})` and removing the `wait()`